# citHeader ignored in citation function in R

Tags: r, citations

I am just curious why the `citHeader` function is ignore in R 3.0.0, because when I use `citation()` to cite my package, the words in the `citHeader` function never appear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's a known bug for now](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15257), though it looks like it'll be fixed in the next minor update.